# How to say pattern recognizer/analyzer or describe someone who can differentiate patterns?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

How to say pattern recognizer/analyzer or describe someone who can differentiate patterns?

The closest thing that I could find was *homo analyticus*. Are there any better descriptors available?
*Homo Discriminaticus* sounds nice but obviously gibberish, Google Translate is of no help either.

Context: I'm not being facetious, this is for a serious project. The term Discrimination is a positive term as in being able to **differentiate** between things/events.

Comment: I thought this was a different question from the newer one. If they are the same, they should be marked duplicate, not deleted. I was just about to give a *different* answer to the other question... Are the two questions about the same thing?

Comment: I took the liberty to add more context from the other question. Feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Greek word [*ἀνάλυσις*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)na%2Flusis) is a reasonable word for "analysis" or "recognition".
It means roughly "understanding by pulling apart", whereas the opposite *σύνθεσις* is more about combining.
The derived adjective [*ἀναλυτικός*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*a%3Aentry+group%3D139%3Aentry%3Da%29nalutiko%2Fs) means "analytical", and it can be borrowed to Latin as *analyticus*.
This appears not to be attested in classical Latin, but it is a loan that would have been understandable to any Roman familiar with the Greek word *ἀνάλυσις*.
Therefore *homo analyticus* is a good choice, and I suggest going with that.
It has the benefit of being easily understandable to a number of people that lack classical education.

However, this expression comes across to me as somewhat humorous, and I would not use it in a serious context.
If you want something more serious, I am not convinced that *homo* and an adjective is a good choice.
Much depends on the broader context.
What language is the text in?
What is the field of study and what people are described with the desired term?

There is a good Latin verb [*diiudicare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=dijudico&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (or *dijudicare*, depending on how you prefer to spell) for distinguishing.
The most natural choice seems to be *diiudicator*, a "distinguisher".
See the linked dictionary entry to see whether the verb means the kind of activity you had in mind.

Judging by [your newer (now deleted) question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5530/79) with some more context, I have the impression that you are looking for something more serious.
Whether either of my two suggestions works depends on the exact context.
In the future, **when you make word requests or ask for short translations, please give context and explain carefully**.
It is really important.

Comment: Thank you for the lightning fast answer and for sharing a link to dictionary. Distinguisher vs Analyst direct vs implied ability to differentiate/discriminate.